# Does CFRETURN in a CFLOCK properly release the lock?

Tags: coldfusion, locking, return, mutual-exclusion

I am writing some code with CFLOCK tags, and am at a point where my code would return somewhere within a CFLOCK.  Example:

```
<cflock timeout="30" name="mylock">
    ... do some processing ...
    <cfif processfailed>
        <cfreturn "">
    </cfif>
    ... some more processing ...
</cflock>
```

If the CFRETURN fires, does the lock get released, or will I need to work my code around some other way?

Comment: Couldn't you test it yourself by running this code, forcing it to fail with a <cfreturn>, then attempting an `exclusive` lock with name `mylock` immediately afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As near as I can tell, it works just fine. But if you are worried about it, just move your cfif outside of the lock block.

Answer (score 2):

The lock gets released when the return fires.